# Where is the first settlement in Red Mars?

Tags: kim-stanley-robinson, mars-trilogy, red-mars

I'm currently reading the [*Mars trilogy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_trilogy) by Kim Stanley Robinson. I'm just in the beginning of the story, they just landed and Nadia just lost her little finger.

I'm quite disoriented by the description of the landscapes and I found the mars map included with the book particularly hard to read and unhelpful. I just remembered the existence of [Google mars](http://www.google.com/mars/) and I found it was a real improvement on the included mars map; I immediately located the 3 aligned volcano that where described. But I'm still disoriented.

Could someone pin-point me exactly where they landed and where they are building the first settlement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a map that can be found at [this site](http://fwb.home.xs4all.nl/rgbmars.html), the original colony was known as "Underhill". Essentially, it's to the east of the Tharsis Bulge, on the other side of the Valles Marinaris

Comment: Around [here](http://www.google.com/mars/#lat=3.864254&lon=-69.345703&zoom=6)?

Comment: @DavRob60: Yeah, that looks about right.